# Service for Ubuntu server to make multiple Website

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, vps

I have a  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server VPS , i want to make a web server to store multiple website (hosting).

Please give me some service to do it.

- LAMP, mysql, phpMyadmin
- Webmin

And anything else?

(Only for web server, not application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the article here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts
Note, this does not only apply to Ubuntu, it should work for any other distro of Linux, and possibly Unix and Mac as well

Lets say you want to have example.com and test.com on your single server.

First you make the file structure like this. You will need a directory for each website in /var/www/, and within each, you need a public_html folder. So your directories should look like this:
/var/www/example.com/public_html/
/var/www/test.com/public_html/

Then you need to give the normal user access to edit these folders, and everyone else access to view them, so run this in terminal:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example.com/public_html 
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/test.com/public_html
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Now you should put and index.html file in each of the public_html directories, and put something in them so you can test that it works well.

Then you will need to create a virtual hosts file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf. This is what the one for example.com should look like. Then you make another one for test.com and copy it, just changing the "example.com" for "test.com".

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

When you finish, you need to enable these virtual hosts files. To do so, you must run the following commands in terminal.

```
sudo a2ensite example.com.conf
sudo a2ensite test.com.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You will most likely receive a message saying something similar to:

```
* Restarting web server apache2 AH00558: apache2: 
Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. 
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

This is a harmless message that does not affect our site.

If you haven't been using actual domain names that you own to test this procedure and have been using some example domains instead, you can at least test the functionality of this process by temporarily modifying the hosts file on your local computer.

assuming that the VPS IP address is 111.111.111.111, you could add the following lines to the bottom of your hosts file:

```
111.111.111.111 example.com
111.111.111.111 test.com
```

This will direct any requests for example.com and test.com on our computer and send them to our server at 111.111.111.111. This is what we want if we are not actually the owners of these domains in order to test our virtual hosts.

Save and close the file.

Now you can test your results. If you go to example.com or test.com, you should see the index.html files you created before.